# Select specific tag on BS4 Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have the following HTML

```
 <li class="product-size__option-wrapper">
            <a onclick="ACC.productDetail.getNewProductSize(this)" data-option-code="000000000196428006" class="product-size__option">
    
                I WANT THIS</a>
        </li>
    <li class="product-size__option-wrapper">
            <a onclick="ACC.productDetail.getNewProductSize(this)" data-option-code="000000000196428007" class="product-size__option product-size__option--no-stock">
    
                I DONT WANT THIS</a>
        </li>
<li class="product-size__option-wrapper">
            <a onclick="ACC.productDetail.getNewProductSize(this)" data-option-code="000000000196428006" class="product-size__option">
    
                I WANT THIS</a>
        </li>
```

I use this code to get the data

```
linksize =soup.find_all('li', class_='product-size__option-wrapper')
            productsize = []
            for size in linksize:
                for size_available in size.find_all('a', {'class':['product-size__option']}):
                    productsize.append(size_available.text.strip())
```

But it gets both tags, since it shares the same class (product-size__option), how can I get only the information I need?

Thanks

Comment: If you just want the first item, then replace find_all() with find() (then you can remove the for loop)

Comment: Its just a example, like the first one i have a lote, same as the second one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data you don't want has a CSS class `product-size__option--no-stock`. You can check if the element does not contain this class, by doing the following check: `if 'product-size__option--no-stock' not in size_available.attrs['class']`

**For example:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''<li class="product-size__option-wrapper">
        <a onclick="ACC.productDetail.getNewProductSize(this)" data-option-code="000000000196428006" class="product-size__option">

            I WANT THIS</a>
    </li>
<li class="product-size__option-wrapper">
        <a onclick="ACC.productDetail.getNewProductSize(this)" data-option-code="000000000196428007" class="product-size__option product-size__option--no-stock">

            I DONT WANT THIS</a>
    </li>'''

    
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,  'html.parser')

linksize =soup.find_all('li', class_='product-size__option-wrapper')
productsize = []
for size in linksize:
    for size_available in size.find_all('a', {'class':['product-size__option']}):
        if 'product-size__option--no-stock' not in size_available.attrs['class']:
            productsize.append(size_available.text.strip())
```